# Circumvent `catch_warnings` context manager bug that resets warning registry, causing unlimited printings of warnings

Tags: python, warnings

Deep inside a module I'm using (`xarray`, but that is not important), a usage of the `catch_warnings` context manager is causing warnings to be printed over and over again, rather than just once as it should.   Without such a context manager, the behaviour is as expected:

```
$ cat ./mwe.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import warnings

for i in range(3):
    try:
        print(i, __warningregistry__)
    except NameError:
        print(i, "first warning")
    warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
    print(i, __warningregistry__)
#    with warnings.catch_warnings():
#        pass
    print(i, __warningregistry__)
    warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
$ ./mwe.py 
0 first warning
./mwe.py:10: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
0 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
0 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
./mwe.py:15: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
1 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
1 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
1 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
2 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
2 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
2 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
```

Uncommenting the context manager causes the warning to be printed every time:

```
$ ./mwe.py 
0 first warning
./mwe.py:10: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
0 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
0 {'version': 0, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
./mwe.py:15: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
1 {'version': 2, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True}
./mwe.py:10: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
1 {'version': 2, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
1 {'version': 2, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
./mwe.py:15: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
2 {'version': 4, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True}
./mwe.py:10: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
2 {'version': 4, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
2 {'version': 4, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 15): True, ("I don't like this.", <class 'UserWarning'>, 10): True}
./mwe.py:15: UserWarning: I don't like this.
  warnings.warn("I don't like this.", UserWarning)
```

I believe it is a consequence of [this semantic change](http://bugs.python.org/issue4180).  I have [posted it as a Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue29672).  I am not sure how to fix the bug.  Is there a workaround that prevents me from being flooded with warning messages that are supposed to be printed only once?  I currently find myself either monkey-patching or avoiding library calls that use `catch_warnings`, neither of which is a particularly desirable workaround.

Comment: Appears to be a consequence of http://bugs.python.org/issue4180