# Python: why is warning printed twice following temporary suppression?

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

It seems that [temporarily suppressing warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) makes repeat warnings **outside of the context manager** display repeatedly.

Example:

```
import warnings

def f():

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=Warning)
        print("A")

    print("B")
    warnings.warn("My warning")


f()
f()
```

Output:

```
A
B
tmp2.py:10: UserWarning: My warning
  warnings.warn("My warning")
A
B
tmp2.py:10: UserWarning: My warning
  warnings.warn("My warning")
```

Also, it does not seem to matter what action and category I give to `simplefilter`.

On the other hand, if I comment out the context `catch_warnings` block,
then the warning only displays once (as intended).

Why? Is it a bug? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue29672)
also asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496579)
with a [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/8232) that seems pretty stale